# cypress button.click doesn't redirect me

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm using cypress for unit tests. I'm doing a verification for the login and i'm sure about the logs but when i click, i am not redirected and i don't know how can i know or see where is the error.

There is my code.

```
describe('espace_parent is functional', () => {
  it('test login parent', () => {

    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
    cy.url().then((url) => {
      cy.task('log',  url)
    })

    cy.contains('parent').click()

    cy.url().then((url) => {
      cy.task('log',  url)
    })

    
    cy.contains('Espace Parent')

    cy.get('*[class^="sc-ezbkAF dYcoMC  "]').clear().type('guigui@guigui.fr')
    cy.get(":input[placeholder='Mot de passe']").clear().type('guigui')
    // cy.contains('Se connecter').click() 
    cy.get('*[class^="sc-giYglK iVKXal"]').click()

    cy.url().then((url) => {
      cy.task('log',  url)
    })


  })
})
```

it gives me this:

espace_parent is functional
http://localhost:3000/
http://localhost:3000/parent/connexion
http://localhost:3000/parent/connexion
✓ test login parent (2839ms)

But normally it should give

http://localhost:3000/
http://localhost:3000/parent/connexion
http://localhost:3000/parent

THe problem is in the 2 nd part of my code:

```
cy.get('*[class^="sc-ezbkAF dYcoMC  "]').clear().type('guigui@guigui.fr')
cy.get(":input[placeholder='Mot de passe']").clear().type('guigui')
// cy.contains('Se connecter').click() 
cy.get('*[class^="sc-giYglK iVKXal"]').click()
```

How can i know, what is wrong, and there is the html than i 'm using

```
<input placeholder="Adresse e-mail" type="text" class="sc-ezbkAF dYcoMC" value="test@gmail.com">
<input placeholder="Mot de passe" type="password" class="sc-ezbkAF dYcoMC" value="test56">
<div class="sc-giYglK iVKXal">
<p class="sc-iJKOTD ecZSkv">Se connecter</p>
</div>
```

Thansk for your help

Comment: This is only a guess, but the first thing I would try is changing to async `it('test login parent', async () => {...}` and then await the button click... `await cy.get('*[class^="sc-giYglK iVKXal"]').click()`. No promises that it works (pun intended), but it's worth a shot

Comment: First thing I would try is to give that button a proper `id` and use it to select an element, since `*[class...]` selectors can be dangerous. You could be just clicking some other element in the page and that's why nothing really happens as the click "works".